# How to check if a given parameter is a symlink/soft link? in bash

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, symlink

I want something similar to this:

```
if [ -d "$1" ] 
then 
echo "Directory"
```

**but with soft link:**

```
if [ ??? "$1" ]
then 
echo "Softlink"
```

Comment: `man bash` `/symbolic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs [Bash-Beginners-Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html):

> [ -h FILE ]   True if FILE exists and is a symbolic link.

Comment: Great answer! tldp.org is sometimes known for errors, It's better to advertise [posix test documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)